# check up on whether the value is set to on RouteConfig.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

It is such that this one should only be used when I go into my index in the news. but if I eg go in and must have known all the news then this here error forward.

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(System.String, Int32)' in
>   'MVCSIte.Controllers.NewController'. An optional parameter must be a
>   reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional
>   parameter. Parameternavn: parameters

**RouteConfig.cs**

It should be such that it just checking up on a few URL and ID otherwise it will not use this one.

```
routes.MapRoute("new", "new/{url}/{id}", new
            {
                controller = "new",
                action = "Index",
                url = UrlParameter.Optional,
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            });
```

**NyhedController.cs**

```
public class New : Controller
{
    DataLinqDB db = new DataLinqDB();

    // GET: Nyhed / here shows the single news
    public ActionResult Index(string url, int id)
    {
        NyhedPage model = new NyhedPage();

        nyheder nyheden = db.nyheders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id && x.url == url);
        if (nyheden != null)
        {
            model.NyhedenTitle = new HtmlString(nyheden.title);
            model.NyhedenDeck = new HtmlString(nyheden.deck);
            model.Tekst = new HtmlString(nyheden.tekst);
        }

        List<nyheder> NyhedsList = db.nyheders.Where(x => x.Id != id && x.url != url).OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).Take(4).ToList();
        model.NyhedsList = NyhedsList.ToList();


        return View(model);
    }
}
```

what I would like to me is that when I go to news since it shows all the news that has this code:

```
//Here it shows all the news
public ActionResult Allenyheder()
    {
        NyhedPage model = new NyhedPage();

        List<nyheder> NyhederIndhold = db.nyheders.Take(12).OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).ToList();
        model.NyhederIndhold = NyhederIndhold.ToList();


        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Your route definition has `controller = "new",` but the controller you have shown is `NyhedController`? And how are you wanting to call these methods?

Comment: @StephenMuecke have i edit its now. sorry

Comment: Unclear what your asking or expecting. How are you calling these methods (and only the last parameter in the route definition can be marked `UrlParameter.Optional`, but since you seem to be always passing both to the method, then remove it from both)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(System.String, Int32)' in 'MVCSIte.Controllers.NewController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter. Parameternavn: parameters

You're seeing this error because your method signature is:

```
public ActionResult Index(string url, int id)
```

Whatever link is sending you to do a get request here, doesn't contain the `{id}` part of the URL. Because `id` isn't nullable, you must pass a value to it, MVC knows that you're trying to access this method, rather than another hence the error. You can either fix whatever is generating the links to include the parameter `id` or you can make `id` a nullable int, or even set a default value (although I don't think this applies in the context of your method).

```
public ActionResult Index(string url, int? id)
{
    if (!id.HasValue) 
    {
        // Return 404 maybe?
    }
    else 
    {
        // Your existing code
    }  
}
```

The problem I think you're having (from your comments) is this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Nyhed", "Allenyheder", "New")
```

You need to pass an `id` parameter in that `ActionLink`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Nyhed", "Allenyheder", "New", new { id = IdOfNewsYouWantHere })
```

Comment: They say that there is error `HasValue` : Error are: **'int' does not contain a definition for 'HasValue' and no extension method 'HasValue' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Comment: @JesperPetersen Did you change `int` to `int?` in your method signature?

Comment: If i add `public ActionResult(string url, int? id)` you will see it with this one error: **method must have a return type**

Comment: @JesperPetersen Ah it should be `public ActionResult Index(string url, int? id)`. Apologies, see edit.

Comment: So the problem is only now that it will not display the page with all the news.

Comment: @JesperPetersen As I said in my answer, your problem is the link you are clicking to activate that method isn't sending an `id`. What's the URL that makes you see this error?

Comment: when I click over to all my news so do I like this `@Html.ActionLink("Nyhed", "Allenyheder", "New")`

Comment: @JesperPetersen you need to pass an id parameter in that ActionLink

Comment: error say: **The name 'IdOfNewsYouWantHere' does not exist in the current context**

Comment: The're not going to send some ID because it will show all the news, you can also look up in my code.

Comment: @JesperPetersen `IdOfNewsYouWantHere` isn't a variable that's why. YOU need to put the `Id` value of the news you want to appear. I really can't help you any more than that, you seem to be struggling with the basic concepts of MVC